# Локальный сервер wifi

Tags: c#, сокет

Окей в классическом понимании сервера и клиента - мы создаем сокет и слушаем определенный порт, клиент подключается к нам по нашему ip и по порту который мы слушаем.

А как допустим поступить в таком случае : у нас есть определенная зона покрытия wifi, даже может быть ряд ретрансляторов. В этой зоне, у нас есть машины - n штук. Каждая из n машин может быть, либо сервером, либо клиентом. И клиент когда хочет подключиться к серверу, он выбирает сервер из множества серверов, которые существуют в пределах покрытия wifi - которые работают в локальной сети.

Вопрос на самом деле раздут до уровня " у нас есть зона покрытия wifi ", не обязательно wifi, может быть даже и ethernet, главное что они все находятся в одной локальной сети.

UPD

по просьбе пользователя `Alexey` уточняю : клиент понятия не имеет к какому серверу он подключается, он не имеет порта и ip адреса. Он просто сканирует локальную сеть на наличие серверов, и подключается, сами сервера могут иметь, допустим, название.

Comment: Уточните вопрос. Не совсем понятно, что именно вы хотите узнать/реализовать. Строго говоря если клиентов-серверов в сети много это ни коим образом не меняет "классического понимания".

Comment: @Alexey добавил в вопрос

Comment: Так, в общем каждая машина в сети изначально не знает о других. Но знает (или только собирается узнать?) все хосты в текущей локальной сети, причём не все из списка - "наши" машины? Если "сервера" всё же ваши и вы определяете порт коммуникации с клиентами то каждый потенциальный клиент раздобыв список хостов поочерёдно опрашивает их на известный порт уточняя, а не сервер ли он. Те кто не сервер-исключаются из списка.

Comment: Ежели ситуация такая, что есть несколько машин в сети, но они не знают о существовании друг друга, и портов подключения не знают то тут я вижу только 1 вариант: каждый ваш сервер с некоторой периодичностью кидает широковещательный UDP пакет в котором сообщает что он сервер и что к нему подключаться по такому-то адресу и такому-то порту.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Не очень понятно, почему вопрос помещен в категорию C# и в чем, собственно, он заключается, но попробую угадать.

Вы хотите иметь возможность подключаться к заранее не известному хосту-порту сервера? Обычно, для таких нужд используются broadcast-UDP пакеты. Схема работы такая: серверы слушают на заранее определенном (и известном клиенту) UDP-порту (например, 15000), клиенты слушают ответы на другом порту (как вариант, динамически выбираемом - не суть, например, 15001). Клиент отправляет широковещательный UPD пакет на этот порт, указывая свой "обратный" порт:

```
UdpClient client = new UdpClient();
IPEndPoint ip = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Broadcast, 15000);
byte[] bytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("15001");
client.Send(bytes, bytes.Length, ip);
client.Close();
```

Сервер, получив пакет, тут же отправляет по обратному адресу ответ, в котором указывает уже свой "рабочий" адрес и порт, ну и всякую служебную информацию, если требуется.

Клиент сразу после отправки начинает какое-то время (например, минуту) слушать ответ(ы) на обратном порту. Получив ответы, он по какому-нибудь принципу (например, по времени отклика, загруженности сервера и т.п.) выбирает нужный ему адрес и дальше начинает уже обычное взаимодействие.

Comment: Просто реализация пишется на C#. То есть по сути когда клиент в момент когда он готов получить список серверов , кидает широковещательный пакет, а затем по откликам серверов, которые дали ответ, можно формировать список серверов в данной локальной сети.